# How to assign a time zone in docker

Tags: docker, timezone, yaml

In activemq

```
  environment:
     - TZ="Asia/Singapore"
```

I mapped the timezone volume of base machine to docker container but it didn't work

```
   volumes:
       - /etc/timezone:/etc/timezone
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Install tz package based on your OS version. please refer below blog for further details.

https://bobcares.com/blog/change-time-in-docker-container/

Comment: I have tried the all steps but it's not works for me